# Data sources in CSV and sequence text file formats and needs to be run as Hadoop MapReduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have my *data sources in CSV and text file* formats and I want to *run Hadoop Map-reduce jobs.*

how do I *convert the data sources into Hadoop Sequence file format* and store in HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for you to convert them to Sequence Files is to run a mapreduce with your default Mapper and Reducer. You will need to specify the OutputFormatClass as SequenceFileOutputFormat. Here is the relevant portion of the driver code.

```
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    // Default Mapper, specified just for clarity
    job.setMapperClass(Mapper.class);
    // Default reducer
    job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);
```

Comment: can u please share the code for mapper, reducer and driver.

Comment: You don't need it. The mapper and reducer specified above are the default Mapper and Reducer. The relevant portion of the driver is shared above.